# Generate all binary combinations possible

Tags: php, recursion

I would like to specify a number of bits, and then get an array containing every possible combination of these bits, in PHP.

Example:

```
number: 3
000
001
010
011
etc...
```

I have tried recursive algorithms which were originally designed for strings, so the algorithm is too slow.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The nice part about bits is that you can do really simple stuff with them. If you want 3 bits, you'll have 7 numbers, which happens to be 8-1. If you want 4 bits, you'll have 15 numbers, which happens to be 16-1. Use this nice fact to make your code simple.

```
$bits = 4;
$max = (1 << $bits);

for ($i = 0; i < $max; $i++) {
    // Use $i
    // echo str_pad(decbin($i), $bits, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

Comment: I thought that the nice part was that enumerating numbers and counting are the same thing.

Comment: @Sosumi PHP has nice [`decbin`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php)and [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)functions.

Comment: So, who downvoted me? And why? You're not going to tell me that there's an easier way to do this, right? :-)

Comment: So using decbin and str_pad on $i will give me every 3-bit combination possible...? Because it doesn't seem to be working for me. I'd like it to go from 000 to 111 and include every combination in between, however it seems to skip some combinations.

Comment: My code will bring you from 0 (0b000) to 7 (0b111) if `$bits` is set to 3, yes. You may like to `str_pad(decbin($i), $bits, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)` to get a string version. (added that to my answer)